# Use jQuery to append a class to every 3rd cloned list item

Tags: jquery

As title says I'm trying to append a class `.third` to every 3rd cloned list element. I have everything working **[here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Klikerko/QFeU7/4/)** except that missing code to add a class. Here is current code:

HTML

```
<ul><li>some text</li></ul>
```

JS

```
$('li').live('click', function() {
    $(this).clone().appendTo('ul');
});
```

CSS

```
li:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:underline;  
}

.third {
  color: #f00;
}
```

At a beginning there is only one list item but, for example, after I click 5 times on any list item I would like to have html that looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li class="third">some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li class="third">some text</li>
</ul>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li').live('click', function() {
    $(this).clone().removeClass('third').appendTo('ul')
        .addClass($('ul').children().length % 3 == 0 ? 'third' : '');
});
```

The difference between this and the other answers is that it doesn't re-traverse the child nodes. It applies the class to the item when added and therefore incurs less overhead (however minimal).

Comment: `addClass('')` doesn't remove the class (in case you click on a link which already has it...); use `toggleClass` or some other fix. Otherwise good idea, I included it in the [performance test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-nth-child-vs-index) I wrote on jsPerf

Comment: @dan: Good catch - see updated code. I made the change in your test and it's still fastest :)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the `:nth-child()` selector ([source](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)). You'll want to use something like

```
$('ul li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('third');
```

[Here is a fully working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QFeU7/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('li').live('click', function() {
    $(this).clone().appendTo('ul');
    $('ul li').removeClass("my-class");
    $('ul li:nth-child(3n)').addClass("my-class");
});
```

Comment: Was going to say you would need to put a `.removeClass()` in first, good edit.

Comment: is the `removeClass()` really needed since all `<li>...</li>` are being appended to the bottom?

Comment: Also, `:nth-child(3)` should be `:nth-child(3n)` I believe

Comment: Hi Phil, looks like your code will add class only to 3rd list item but I need to append this class to **every** 3rd list item.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

See the [jQuery nth-child documentation](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) for examples:

```
$('li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('third');
```

Answer (score 1):

`nth-child(3)` could be a little slow (see [jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-nth-child-vs-index) => 50% slower). You can consider using [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
$('li').live('click', function() {
  var $clone = $(this).clone().appendTo('ul');
  $clone.toggleClass('third', $clone.index() % 3 == 2);
});
```